# Multiple Image outputs

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, batch

I'd like to output different sizes of the same image from photoshop all at the same time. For example, I have a 1920x150 banner that I would like to output into smaller sizes but the same dimensions, and multiple different sizes all at the same time?

How would I go about getting photoshop to do all that at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record an action or write a script that performs all the operations you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Photoshop can accomplish this, but [Image Resizer](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/digitalphotography/learnmore/tips/eschelman2.mspx) would be able to quickly modify your images after esaved from PhotoShop.